# How to use the Object Variables in parameter value in ADF Azure DevOps Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I used the variable **trigger_time** to overwrite the default value of the ARM template as shown below,
[image]

But **trigger_time** is a json object, so while I try to overwrite the default parameter value while deploying as below
[image]

It will treat the json object as a string like   **'**{"minutes":[10],"hours":[18]}**'**  instead of  `{"minutes":[10],"hours":[18]}` and **fails** the deployment.

I tried to convert the string to JSON **${{ convertToJson(trigger_time) }}** but this didn't solve my problem.